# Difference between On-die and junction temperature

Tags: fpga, temperature, xilinx

What is the difference between junction and on-die temperature.
I am using Xilinx Artix-7 FPGA

Answer (score 1):

On-die temperature and junction temperatures are similar, the difference being:

**On die temperature** measurement is possible only if the device has a specific temperature diode sensor. On-die temperature is typically used by end use customers for various purposes - auto shutdown / power management / etc.

**Junction temperature**, on the other hand, is an approximation of the temperature based on calculation. whereas junction temperature is typically used by the chip manufacturer during characterization or manufacturing flow  or similar purposes.

**Here is an on die temp measurement circuit for Intel Agilex**

> https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/hb/agilex/ug-ag-pwr.pdf.

[image]

Comment: updated - thanks